# History of Betrothal view marriage and divorce

Tags: comparative-christianity

What is the history of the Betrothal View regarding Marriage and Divorce? Am I right in understanding that this view does not permit divorce for ANY reason? Which Christian denominations significantly or entirely follow this teaching?

I seem to recall reading a long time ago that this teaching, which apparently has its roots in ancient Judaism, was eventually used by some Christians or denominations as a way of justifying or even manipulating a "no divorce for any reason" stance, even though a literal, straightforward reading of the scriptures in question would seem to clearly allow divorce for one reason only--that of fornication.

Here are the two key verses regarding the betrothal/no divorce issue as follows (correct me if I am wrong):

> But I say unto you, That whosoever shall put away his wife, saving for the cause of fornication, causeth her to commit adultery: and whosoever shall marry her that is divorced committeth adultery. - Mat 5:32 KJV

> And I say unto you, Whosoever shall put away his wife, except [it be] for fornication, and shall marry another, committeth adultery: and whoso marrieth her which is put away doth commit adultery. - Mat 19:9 KJV

Is it true that one or more church denominations (Independent Fundamental Baptists (IFB) in particular) held to an allowance for divorce for fornication only and no other reason throughout most of church history, but then at a later era ((I think I recall from an article  I once read that such a change may have been made about 100 years ago) that the IFB or other denomination(s) changed what appears to be the literal allowance to divorce for "fornication only" in the scriptures above to a new view which forbade divorce for any reason, including fornication?

**Please only answer the questions regarding the betrothal issue on marriage and divorce from the historical viewpoint, which is where my questions are focused!!!**

I request this as I know this is a "hot topic" throughout the ages of the church, and will generate endless posts on what Christians believe to be true or false regarding reasons for divorce or no divorce, and I don't want us to get bogged down in that issue.

Comment: I think you have answered your own question with the verses you have quoted. It is not clear to me why you need any other information about this matter.

Comment: What is the "Betrothal View"? Can you give some links to sources discussing it?